# addEventListener has no effect when button clicked. (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

May I ask for help why my `addEventListener` is not getting work out and does not click the button? Yet, whenever I pressed the keyboard buttons on my keyboard it works.

I am practicing the projects from the Web Development Bootcamp Course I took by Angela Yu. Hoping for an answer!

Here is the code:

HTML

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Piano Kit</title>

    <!-- CSS Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/">
    
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:wght@400;700&family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

    <div class="flex-container">
        <img class="grandPiano" src="images/grandPianoIcon.png" alt="grandPiano.png">    
    </div>
   
    <div class="grid-container">
        <button class="a key">do</button>
        <button class="s key">re</button>
        <button class="d key">mi</button>
        <button class="f key">fa</button>
        <button class="h key">sol</button>
        <button class="j key">la</button>
        <button class="k key">ti</button>
        <button class="l key">do</button>
    </div>

   
  

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```js
       // Detecting Button Press
        var numberOfPianoKeyButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".key").length;
        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfPianoKeyButtons; i++) {
        document.querySelectorAll(".key")[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        var buttonInnerHTML = this.innerHTML

        // audio
        makeSound (buttonInnerHTML);

        // animation
        buttonAnimation (buttonInnerHTML);

    });

    }



    // Detecting Keyboard Press
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
        // alert("Key was pressed!");
        // console.log(event);

        // audio
        makeSound(event.key);

        buttonAnimation(event.key);

    });


    // Detecting Sound Audio
    function makeSound(key) {

           // audio
            //    switch (buttonInnerHTML)
            switch (key) {
                case "a":
                    var piano1 = new Audio('sounds/piano1.mp3');
                    piano1.play();
                break;
                
                case "s":
                    var piano2 = new Audio('sounds/piano2.mp3');
                    piano2.play();
                break;
    
    
                case "d":
                    var piano3 = new Audio('sounds/piano3.mp3');
                    piano3.play();
                break;
    
    
                case "f":
                    var piano4 = new Audio('sounds/piano4.mp3');
                    piano4.play();
                break;
    
    
    
                case "h":
                    var piano5 = new Audio('sounds/piano5.mp3');
                    piano5.play();
                break;
    
    
                case "j":
                    var piano6 = new Audio('sounds/piano6.mp3');
                    piano6.play();
                break;
    
    
                case "k":
                    var piano7 = new Audio('sounds/piano7.mp3');
                    piano7.play();
                break;
    
                case "l":
                    var piano8 = new Audio('sounds/piano8.mp3');
                    piano8.play();
                break;
    
    


            default: console.log(buttonInnerHTML);
        }
    }



    // Button Animation
    function buttonAnimation(currentKey) {
        var activeButton = document.querySelector("." + currentKey)
        activeButton.classList.add("pressed");

        // timeout function
        // setTimeout(function, milliseconds, param1, param2, ...)
        setTimeout(function() {
            activeButton.classList.remove('pressed');
        }, 100);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for that I am going to change the Title, I just put the year.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code, you need to define the key through which the value will be sent (data-key).

```
<button data-key="a" class="a key">do</button>
<button data-key="s" class="s key">re</button>
<button data-key="d" class="d key">mi</button>
<button data-key="f" class="f key">fa</button>
<button data-key="h" class="h key">sol</button>
<button data-key="j" class="j key">la</button>
<button data-key="k" class="k key">ti</button>
<button data-key="l" class="l key">do</button>
```

For the click delay, you need to find out the key value for this element:

```
var pianoKeyButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".key");

pianoKeyButtons.forEach(function (button) {
    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var key = this.getAttribute('data-key');

        // audio
        makeSound (key);
        // animation
        buttonAnimation (key);
    });
})
```

Comment: Hi Richard Dobron, Thanks for the guide! Grateful for it.